# Access value from parent from PartialView MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i need to maintain student interest in edit mode
there is partial view where
two list boxes  - one for current interest and other for available (which are not added in student profile)
each interest has a ajax Action link. when i click on it it add to student current interest.
problem is that-- i need to send student id with it which is from parent view( ie not from partial view), 
and student id is in url
or -- how can i access student id in partial view

// Code sample

```
@model StdMan.Models.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Project</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StId)
        </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
            Intested In              
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field" id="Interest">
          @Html.Action("PartialAddInterest", "Interest")
        </div>  

     </fieldset>
    <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
}
```

//////////
-- PartialView
PartialAddInterest.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<StdMan.Models.Interest>

<table>
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Added)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Name

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Remove", "RemoveInterest",new { id = item.IsId },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "Interest",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "GET"
    })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

<table>

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Rem)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Name

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Add", "AddInterest", new { id = item.IsId },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "Interest",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "GET"
    })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I have to pass model.StId with Ajax Actionlink
like @Ajax.ActionLink("Add", "AddInterest", new { id = item.IsId, StId = @Model.StId },

In controller

```
 public ActionResult AddInterest( int id, int StId)
 {
          //logic to add interest in specific student profile depend on StId
 }
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, thanks for reply i add some code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the student id to the `PartialAddTool` child action:

```
@Html.Action("PartialAddTool", "Interest", new { id = Model.StId })
```

and now the controller action will have the student id:

```
public ActionResult PartialAddTool(int stdId)
{
    ...
}
```

Now all that's left is have the `PartialAddTool` action set some property on the view model that is passed to the partial view. Currently this partial view seems to be strongly typed to `IEnumerable<StdMan.Models.Interest>` but you could create a new view model which has 2 properties: the student id and a collection of interests. This way the partial view will have the student id and it could be used when generating the links to finally be passed to the `AddInterest` action.